# Как можно отслеживать нажатие средней кнопки мыши на питоне

Tags: python, linux, pyautogui

Способ должен обязательно работать на Линуксе и было бы не плохо использовать модуль pyautogui, но это не принципиально

Comment: Смотрите `libinput`, и её биндинги для питона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дать права на прослушку

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

потом или перезагрузиться. Установи свежую версию.

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/python-libinput.git
```

Код

```
from libinput import LibInput, ContextType, EventType
li = LibInput(context_type=ContextType.UDEV)
li.assign_seat('seat0') # добавит все устройства

for event in filter(
        lambda x: x.type == EventType.POINTER_BUTTON and x.button == 274,
        li.events
):
    print('нажата средняя кнопка')
```